# How do I trigger a angularjs page refresh in a global callback function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm currently interacting with the google api, using jsonp, so I need a global callback function. How do I trigger an update of the page inside the callback function?

I've tried `$timeout` and `$scope.$apply`, but they don't seem to work.

In my controller, I have something like

```
var App = window.App = angular.module('App', ["App.controllers"]);
angular.module('App.Controllers', [])
    .controller("LoginController", ["$scope", function($scope) {
        window.gplusUserCallback = function(data) {
            $timeout(function() {
                $scope.user = data;
                console.log("gplusUserCallback", $scope.user);
            });
        };
    }]);
```

But `$scope.user` doesn't seem to trigger a refresh. Any ideas?

Comment: Where is `$scope` defined?

Comment: Why would `$scope.user` trigger a refresh?

Comment: You have the get the angular scope and call the $digest function to trigger a check on changed values and update the databindings.

Comment: The code is wrapped around a controller declaration, so `$scope` is injected. I've updated the code snippet to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get your angular scope updated after the global callback was triggered you have to manually update your scope.

```
// If you do have access to your scope via $scope
$scope.$digest();

// If you don't have access to the scope
var element = document.getElementById('dashboard');
// Get the scope for your element where your controller is bound to
var scope = angular.element(element).scope();
scope.$digest();
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. Wouldn't `$digest` be the same as `$apply`? Actually `$apply` seems to be better, as per http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html